# Read JNDI Database name from properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jndi

How can I read `jdbc/DatabaseName` from a properties file with the following content?

```xml
<bean id="DatabaseName" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: **<bean id="DatabaseName" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DatabaseName"/>
</bean>**

Answer (score 0):

This question is very unclear.

I assume you just want to get the key-value stuff from property file.

In that case, you simply just read the property file like so, and iterate over keys and values like so:

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("path/to/yourpropertyfile.properties")) {

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // print out values from properties
            prop.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", Value : " + v));

}
```

It will spit out all of the details you need.